# H2 database simply does not create 2 of the columns, but only, if it is built without DATAGEN profile

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am in the finish line of a university assignment where we have to develop a fullstack application with a Spring-Boot - Java - H2 backend (build tool: Maven).

Part of the assignment is, that if the profile **datagen** is set when starting, the application must be able to insert a test dataset.

I use IntelliJ for my project, I configured and used the datagen facility throughout the development and only run the application today for a check without it: mvn clean compile spring-boot:run

I realised, that when I want to add data to the database, I get an BadSQLGrammarException. I tried to debug it, and came to the consequence (with the help of the H2 console), that 2 columns of my horse table are literally not created for any reason.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS horse
(
    id            BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(255)            NOT NULL,
    description   VARCHAR(255),
    date_of_birth DATE                    NOT NULL,
    sex           ENUM ('MALE', 'FEMALE') NOT NULL,
    owner_id      BIGINT,
    parent_1_id   BIGINT,
    parent_2_id   BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owner (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

ALTER TABLE horse ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_1_id) REFERENCES horse(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE horse ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_2_id) REFERENCES horse(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Please help, I have no idea, how it is possible!

Thanks in advance:

Peter

Pictures here (I do not have enough reputations to post them normally, it seems):
[intellij with the compile time errors and with the create table sql script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdiL2.png)
[h2 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS6eC.png)

As I wanted to add data to the database (through the running application frontend), I got a BadSQLGrammarException. I tried to debug it, and came to the consequence (with the help of the H2 console), that 2 columns of my horse table are literally not created.

Comment: can you run your applicaiton without Alter queries and check if parent_1_id  and  parent_2_id   field are created.

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that before asking. It did not help. In the end, I just deleted the database files and after their regeneration by the next run everything worked perfectly.